# Android Broadcast receiver unit test

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android and learning `BroadcastReceiver`. I am trying to `sendBroadcast` Receiver from Android unit test, and trying to check if the intent action received by the receiver is valid. If I want to send intent data from receiver to unit test, what is the way.

```
public class ExampleUnitTest {
    private Context mContext;
    private AsyncTableProcess sgTable;
    private final static String WHOLE_HOME_ASYNC = "com.atv.intent.action.WHOLE_HOME_AE";

    // Executes each task synchronously using Architecture Components.
    @Rule
    public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mContext = mock(Context.class);
        sgTable = new AsyncTableProcess();
    }
    @Test
    public void addition_isCorrect() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        filter.addAction(WHOLE_HOME_ASYNC);
        mContext.registerReceiver(sgTable, filter);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(WHOLE_HOME_ASYNC);
        intent.putExtras(setWholeHomeBundleExtras());
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
   }
}

public class AsyncTableProcess extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String sgsLiteWholeHomeAE = "com.atv.intent.action.WHOLE_HOME_AE";


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String message = intent.getAction();

        //Response back to unitTest.
        switch (message) {
            case sgsLiteWholeHomeAE:
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
                //updating hash table..
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can not do unit test for android components without a device. However using Robolectric can make it work. Here is how i have implemented unit test for BroadcastReceiver.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(sdk = 29)
@DoNotInstrument
public class BroadCastReceiverTest extends TestCase {
  private Context context;
  private YourReceiver yourReceiver;
  private int expectedResponseCode = 500;
  @Before
  public void setup(){
    yourReceiver = new YourReceiver();
    context = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
    intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_YOUR_ACTION);
  }

  @Test
  public void testResponse(){
    intent.putExtra(Constants.ERROR_CODE,500);
    yourReceiver.onReceive(context,intent);
    assertEquals(expectedResponseCode,yourReceiver.getResponseCode());

  }
}
```